# Printing the output of Spawn commands

Tags: expect

I am new to Expect and the program is executed on my machine to login into Remote IBM host and Execute the script.
But the output is not displayed in my local system console or the terminal where the script is executed.

Sample code:

```
expect -c "
     spawn ssh @hostname "./ibm_nettrace.sh;ls -ltr;mkdir netos;"
     expect eof
     "
```

Here,the shell script fails due to file permission.
But the errors are not routed into my console.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to escape quotation inside quotation like this.

```
expect -c "
 spawn ssh @hostname \"./ibm_nettrace.sh;ls -ltr;mkdir netos;\"
 expect eof
 "
```

Or, by using single quote like this:

```
expect -c '
 spawn ssh @hostname "./ibm_nettrace.sh;ls -ltr;mkdir netos;"
 expect eof
 '
```

Comment: Or use Tcl braces in the spawn call: `expect -c "spawn ... {...}; ..."`